# Cannot find javax.crypto

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run this `Amazon Token Vending Machine` `ant` [project](http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990) in `eclipse` to try to recompile a new `.war file` with a policy that matches my policy but when I import it I get build errors saying that it cannot find `javax.crypto`

is there something else I need to import into the project to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have do download the `javax-crypto.jar` and add it to the classpath of your project.

Comment: I thought javax.crypto was included in the jce.jar file included in the JRE?